# Making Dired work with FTP on OS X 10.13

Tags: dired, osx, tramp, ftp

So apparently Apple has (stupidly) dropped support for "insecure" Unix commands such as `telnet`, `ftp`, etc. in 10.13, or "High Sierra" (see [these](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79056) [threads](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79241) for more info). Unfortunately, I use Dired as an `ftp` client to [lists.gnu.org](ftp://lists.gnu.org/). So, to compensate for the loss of BSD's `ftp`, I installed the GNU `inetutils` from homebrew:

```
brew install inetutils
```

However, GNU's `ftp` seems to behave quite differently. For starters, I now have to *explicitly* provide a username and "password" and turn on passive mode. For example:

```
C-x C-f /ftp:ftp@lists.gnu.org:
ftp> open lists.gnu.org
open lists.gnu.org
Connected to lists.gnu.org.
220 Welcome to lists.gnu.org MBOX FTP service.
ftp> ls
ls
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp> user ftp
user ftp
331 Please specify the password.
Password: my@email.com

230 Login successful.
ftp> ls
ls
500 Illegal PORT command.
500 Unknown command.
ftp> passive
passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> ls
ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (208,118,235,17,81,10).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      500          4096 Mar 08  2012 123tkshop-announce
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      500          4096 Jan 08  2007 123tkshop-bugs
drwxr-xr-x    2 500      500          4096 Jan 05  2007 123tkshop-devoloper
...
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

Previously, with BSD's `ftp`, all of this login stuff would automatically happen when I tried to connect.

Yet even though `ls` now works in the `ftp` command prompt, I cannot get a Dired buffer for the remote host. Even after I've logged in (as above), when I try to run `find-file` on `/ftp:ftp@lists.gnu.org:` I get the following errors in `*Messages*`:

```
Getting PWD... [8 times]
tramp-file-name-handler: Unable to obtain CWD
```

And I see the following in the `ftp` command prompt:

```
ftp> pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
pwd
257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp> 257 "/"
ftp>
```

And I get no Dired buffer for the remote host.

So my question is: How can I use Dired to interact with `ftp` hosts on OS X 10.13?

PS:

I noticed that these issues *do not* occur in Emacs on Ubuntu. And for good measure, I copied BSD's `ftp` from another Mac and verified that none of these issues occur when I use that instead of GNU's `ftp`.

I am using Emacs 25.3 (on both my OS X and Ubuntu systems).

Comment: This sounds like a bug.

Comment: TRAMP, since it is GNU, should support GNU ftp right? So this is probably a bug in the macOS port of Emacs? Where can I download BSD ftp?

Comment: @AlanThird Do you mean a bug with Dired? Or with `ftp`?

Comment: @cjohansson Yes, one would think that GNU `ftp` would work great with Emacs. I'll make a post on the `bug-gnu-emacs` mailing list and see if this is a problem with the macOS port of Emacs. Also, [here is FreeBSD's `ftp`,](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/11.1.0/usr.bin/ftp/) although it may be different from [Apple's `ftp`.](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/lukemftp/)

Comment: With Emacs, specifically ange-ftp. I don't see anything in the code that is macOS or BSD specific, so my guess is it should Just Work.

Comment: When I used the Apple `ftp` it worked. Using `(setq ange-ftp-ftp-program-args '("-i" "-g" "-v"))` Emacs is able to login using GNU `ftp` but dired still doesn't work

Comment: @AlanThird Yes, it should Just Work. I suppose it ought to be filed as a bug on `bug-gnu-emacs`; I haven't gotten around to doing that yet, though.

Comment: @cjohansson I noticed no differences by running `(setq ange-ftp-ftp-program-args '("-i" "-g" "-v"))`. However, yes: Apple `ftp` works totally fine, so there must be something wrong with GNU `ftp`. Or, at least, with the way that Emacs is treating it.

Comment: @AlanThird I [put up a post on `bug-gnu-emacs`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-10/msg00074.html) in case this is a problem with the Emacs build for macOS.

Comment: @cjohansson I [put up a post on `bug-gnu-emacs`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-10/msg00074.html) in case this is a problem with the Emacs build for macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to work around this problem by using [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312273/79496) instead of `inetutils`.

Comment: I've got that installed, no change in behavior.

Comment: @BretWeinraub Sorry, not sure how to help you there. It solved the issue when I did it.